# How to pass data from parent to child component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Header (The parent component) consists of header + tab menu, and Contents (The child component) must be change by tab menu. What I want to do is when click a tab menu(Parent), content scroll to top (Child) To see the latest posts.

[image]

So, How can I send my click event from parent to child ?

Can you suggest the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using props, you can send data or events to child component, Try this:

In parent Component-

```
_handleOnclick(text){
    console.log('in parent component', text);
}

render(){
   return(
     <Child onClick={this._handleOnclick.bind(this)}/>
   )
}
```

In Child Component-

```
_handleClick(){
   console.log('in child component');
   this.props.onClick('child calling');
}

render(){
    return(
       <p onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>Click Me</p>
    )
}
```

Check the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/px2dphje/2/

Comment: Thank you so much @Mayank ! I'll try ASAP !